# How to limit usage of unique library files to one specific program

Tags: permissions, libraries

I need to install and use a hardware management & monitor utility program provided by the manufacturer of my RAID adapter.

Their program installs two specific required library files (libssl.o and libcrypto.o).

Those two files become the system default ssl and crypto library support and get used by all other applications, causing multiple other programs to fail for unmet ssl and/or crypto support dependencies.

How can I fence off these two support libraries so they are only used by my RAID management utility program but not by any other applications?

Comment: can you install those two libraries in a private folder (e.g. /home/) which isn't in the path of the other applications?

Comment: can you give those libraries a different/unique name, which won't be used by other application, and will be used by the RAID software?

Comment: Thx, I will see if that is possible. The RAID management utility is packaged as a *.deb so I'm not sure it's possible to modify any of the installation settings.  I've never attempted anything like that.